# Is this code for a for loop odd numbers generator in python valid?

Tags: python

```
a = 0
for a in range(1,99):
  a = (a + 2)
  y = a
  print(y)
```

This is the code I used to try and generate odd numbers between 1 to 99.However it does not show any results. The problem is ,I wanna keep the same structure of the code , with any problems in it being rectified and I might want to add to it but I dont wanna write new code altogether as I might not understand it due to me being new at Python. Thanks in advance guys.

PS - The problem I get in this is that it prints all the numbers in the range instead of only odd ones.

Edit : 31/03/21 : Thanks to all of the people who helped me with the solution :D I asked this question when I was way younger so I apologise if it sounds really weird :D

Comment: last three lines can be simplified down to just `print( a + 2 )`

Comment: What steps have you taken to debug your issue? What happens when you step through with the debugger?

Comment: Your code shows (wrong) output, but it still shows results.

Comment: What, **exactly** is the problem? Are you getting an exception when you run this? Is there an error message? Or are you just not getting the results you expect. These are the things you should be explicitly addressing in your question.

Comment: You can use `sum(range(1,99))`

Comment: @marni It would be `range(1, 101, 2)`, since `range` would stop at `99`

Comment: @marni you can use `(98*99)//2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you shouldn't be modifying `a` inside the loop, since it is being set automatically by the `range` line.

```
a = 0   #unneeded
for a in range(1,99):   #first time sets a to 1
  a = (a + 2)  # sets a to 3
  y = a        # sets y to 3
  print(y)     # prints y
# loop back to beginning
for a in range(1,99):   #sets a to 2
  a = (a + 2)  # sets a to 4
  y = a        # sets y to 4
  ...
```

You can either change the loop iterator to a different variable:  `for _ in range(50):`

Or you can do something more pythonic by using the range function to set `a` and not modify it in the loop body:  `for a in range(1,100,2): print(a)`

Answer (score 2):

this is more concise:

```
for a in range(1, 100, 2):
print(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code

> a = (a + 2)

only increase value of "a".

You can get odd numbers from any type of numeric sequences in this way:

```
for a in range(1,100):
    if a % 2 != 0:
        print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `range` for this!

```py
>>> l=1 # start
>>> r=20 # end
>>> range(l if l % 2 else l+1, r+1, 2)
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19]
```

Comment: Please add a comment describing how this code solves the problem and what was the original problem's cause.